# How can I fix a div under my original header if it changes height when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fixed

I created an additional menu bar (`.secondnav`) that I want to place right below the original header (`#headAnnouncementWrapper`) in a website. The problem is, when scrolling, the header's height changes when going from relative position to fixed at the top, and also when on mobile.

I've been trying with this:

```
 var scrolled = 78;
   var headHeight = $('#headerAnnouncementWrapper').height();
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrolled) {
  $('.secondnav').css('position', 'fixed');
  $('.secondnav').css('top', headHeight);
} else {
  $('.secondnav').css('position', 'relative'),
  $('.secondnav').css('top', headHeight);
}
  });
```

But I don't know how I should be calculating the `headHeight` variable so it changes when the height changes, and how to use that result as the top value for the `.secondnav`'s css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the height of the main header inside the scroll event. Each time the scroll event triggers, it will recheck the height. Then, the next line will adjust the top margin of the lower header to match the height of the upper header. Top-margin here replaces your position method.

```
var scrolled = 78;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var headHeight = $('#headerAnnouncementWrapper').height();
   $('.secondnav').css('marginTop', headHeight);
if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrolled) {
  $('.secondnav').css('position', 'fixed');
} else {
  $('.secondnav').css('position', 'relative'),
}
  });
```